# Question about what I should have before Connect

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I have this included:

```
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket(), connect(), send(), and recv() */

/* Establish the connection to the echo server */
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr, sizeof(echoServAddr)) < 0)
    DieWithError("connect() failed");
```

But I am getting this:

> TCPClient.cpp:395: error: no matching
>   function for call to
>   ‘ClientHandler::connect(int&,
>   sockaddr*, unsigned int)’

The thing is I am also using QT.

should I have somethihng before "connect"...
SOMETHING::connect(....)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have your own class ClientHandler with a connect method. To avoid confusion call connect from the global namespace:

```
::connect ( sock, ...
```

Comment: Ahh, so what does that
"::" do anyways?

I know i had to do it before to use cout

i had std::cout

but what does it really mean

Comment: @Nero: All functions outside namespaces and classes (generally all c library functions) are in the global namespace, that is their full qualified names look like ::function_name. The "::" is not usually needed, except in cases where you have a local (not in global namespace) function with the same name.